# SQL: How to calculate correctly with any DATE_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime-format

I have created a table where I listed some spare parts of my company.
The Table looks like this:

```
ID | Name | install_date | last_changed | order_nr. | WearStatus
----------
1  | "ABC" | **2017-11-08 10:34:40** | NULL | 123456 | **50**<br>
2  | "DEF" | **2017-11-08 10:34:40** | NULL | 654321 | **10**<br>
```

.
.

I want to calculate the Future Date, where the spare Parts should be changed. For example:
I installed a Part on the 01. December and exactly 10 Days later on the 11. December this part has a Wear of 50%, then I know: It has 10 more Days left.

My calculation is according to the rule of three formula: **Time = (100 * delta t) / Wear**

I use the following SQL command:

```
SELECT ( (100*(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - First_Usage) / Wear) + First_Usage) As 'Change_Date' FROM spare_parts
```

And get the following Results:

[image]

If you see there are some crazy DATE_TIMES like **2017-19-41-43-19-31**. 

So my Question is now: How to format this "Numbers" to a useful DATE_TIME Format like **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss** ?

kind regards Toby

Comment: install_date is a datetime field ?

Comment: Have you tried TO_DATE('expression you are using')  ?

Comment: Yes it is DATE_TIME. And WearStatus is Integer. The Result (Change_Date) should be also DATE_TIME. greetings

Comment: Please make use of TIMESTAMPDIFF() and TIMESTAMPADD() functions and you wont get any 'funny' dates.

Comment: Thanks @NkoleEvans ! Didn't know something about this 2 functions :)

Comment: This works for me: SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(second, TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,First_Usage,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), NOW()) from spare_parts;

Comment: You welcome, glad you have used the functions to solve your problem so quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 approaches:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(First_Usage, INTERVAL (100*(DATEDIFF(NOW(),First_Usage) / Wear)) day)) As 'Change_Date' FROM spare_parts
```

or

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( (100*(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(First_Usage)) / Wear) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(First_Usage))) As 'Change_Date' FROM spare_parts
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL olredy have date intervals functional. If in Wear is already days count, your variant is

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(First_Usage, INTERVAL Wear DAY) as 'Change_Date' FROM spare_parts;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add